# CAAnimation -1 repeat count?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

how can i make my `CAKeyframeAnimation` have a never ending repeat count?

I tried `animation.repeatCount = -1;` but it only repeats once.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try `animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;`

Comment: Float.infinity in Swift

Answer (score 41):

You can also use

```
animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
```

This is exactly the same as HUGE_VALF, but I prefer INFINITY as it speaks by itself.

Comment: Float.infinity in Swift

Answer (score 7):

From the documentation for the [CAMediaTiming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CAMediaTiming) protocol:

> Setting this property to `HUGE_VALF` will cause the animation to repeat forever.

Answer (score 5):

In Swift I'm using the following code:

```
let animation = CATransition()
animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
```

Answer (score 2):

Just go to definition!
There is no matter what it will be: either HUGE_VALF or INFINITY.
Because:

(math.h:)

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#   define    HUGE_VAL     __builtin_huge_val()
#   define    HUGE_VALF    __builtin_huge_valf()
#   define    HUGE_VALL    __builtin_huge_vall()
#   define    NAN          __builtin_nanf("0x7fc00000")
#else
#   define    HUGE_VAL     1e500
#   define    HUGE_VALF    1e50f
#   define    HUGE_VALL    1e5000L
#   define    NAN          __nan()
#endif

#define INFINITY    HUGE_VALF
```

and finally (according to math.c):

```
/* FUNCTION: __builtin_huge_valf */   
inline float __builtin_huge_valf(void) { return 1.0f/0.0f; }
```

So each option will be ok:

```
animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
animation.repeatCount = __builtin_huge_valf();
animation.repeatCount = 1.0f/0.0f;
```